# Need Help In Moving An Item

Tags: java, list

I am trying to move an item in a list upward but it is not working the way I want.  The element that I select still remains after it has swapped position with the previous elements.  I am using Jlist.

listTasks is a JLIst
and
listModel is ListModel

For instance if I have

```
1
2
```

as a list, after I select 2 and click the up button I get

```
2
1
2
```

This is the code snippet :

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int id = 0;
        if(e.getSource() == this.lblUpArrow){
            id = this.listTasks.getSelectedIndex();
            if((id > 0 ) && (this.listModel.size() != 0)){
                Object value = this.listModel.getElementAt(id);
                Object previousValue = this.listModel.getElementAt(id - 1);
                this.listModel.insertElementAt(value.toString(), (id - 1));

                this.listTasks.remove(id);
                this.listModel.insertElementAt(previousValue.toString(), (id));

                this.listModel.remove(id + 1);

            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you explain why you're removing items from `this.listTasks`, but adding items to `this.listModel`?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. 
I tried to remove from listModel first and it was not working so i tried the listTasks if maybe it will fix the problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the element to move and re-insert it above the current position. No swap required.

Comment: You should also realize that your code is performing an insertion that will invalidate the value of id (that should really be called "index").